# Remove values that net each other out to zero, leaving only one positive 2472320 in this case

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
492953BI    -2284424
492953BI    -2014941
492953BI    -1916038
492953BI    -1908036
```

I need to split the first coloumn (ID) into two coloumns. (ie. Have the numbers in first coloumn, and BI in the second.) Am battling to do this on SQL Server. Am also new to SQL so battling to work with older questions, thank you

Comment: I see I have entered this incorrectly, there is a coloumn (ID) that basically has all the "492953BI" values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Left()` and `Right()` functions:

```
--If the number part is always 6 digits
Select left(yourColumn,6) Col1, right(yourColumn,2) Col2
From yourTable

--For any number of front digits (bit more generic)
Select left(yourCol, charIndex('B',yourCol)-1) Col1, 
       right(yourCol, len(yourCol) - charIndex('B',yourCol)+ 1) Col2
From yourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select substring(col1, 1, 6) as new_col1, 
       substring(col1, 7, 2) as new_col2
from your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select substring(ID, 1, 6) as ID, 
   substring(ID, 7, 2) as SubID from Table
```

this may give result as in two column ID and SubID.

thanks